# Adding library dependencies to interface libraries in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

find_package(fmt)

add_library(mylib INTERFACE )
add_dependencies(mylib  fmt::fmt-header-only)
target_compile_features(mylib INTERFACE cxx_std_20)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE .)

add_executable(test_exe test_exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_exe PUBLIC mylib)
```

But `fmt` is not linked against `test_exe` unless I explicitly add it to the dependencies. Am I defining the dependencies of `mylib` wrong?

The error is the following and it goes away if I add `fmt::header-only` to the link libraries of `test_exe`

```
fatal error: 'fmt/format.h' file not found
#include <fmt/format.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: If you want transitively propagate linkage with `fmt::fmt-header-only` when one links with `mylib`, then use `target_link_libraries` instead of `add_dependencies`:  `target_link_libraries(mylib INTERFACE fmt::fmt-header-only)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. Would you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_dependencies(mylib  fmt::fmt-header-only)
```

simply makes sure that the target `fmt::fmt-header-only` is up to date before `mylib` is built. It doesn't link `fmt::fmt-header-only` regardless of the target type of `mylib`. Linking is done via `target_link_libraries`

```
target_link_libraries(mylib INTERFACE fmt::fmt-header-only)
```